# Get Query Faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I create a Table as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_10](
  [Name] [nchar](10) NULL,
  [Date] [datetime] NULL
)
```

after created a clustered index on [Date]

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX index_name10   
ON dbo.table_10 ([Date]);
```

then filled the table with 80K of data randomly(but in ordered datetime)

run this query and finished about 1 minute

I expect this runs faster because I think nested query can be done in logarithmic time. but seems it's not, where I am wrong or how to do it faster?

```
SELECT Table_10.[date], (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                                       Table_10 AS t10 
                                       WITH(INDEX(index_name10))
                                       WHERE table_10.[date] < t10.[Date])

FROM table_10
```

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: sql-server tag added

Comment: It doesn't matter that you do your inserts ordered by datetime. For the DBMS the table is still an unordered set of data.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using SQL Server.  You can use `rank()` for this purpose:

```
select t.*,
       (rank() over (order by [date]) - 1)
from table_10;
```

If `[date]` has no duplicates, then it is clearer to use `row_number()` instead:

```
select t.*,
       (row_number() over (order by [date]) - 1)
from table_10;
```

The `- 1` is only needed because you seem to want to start the numbering at 0 rather than 1.

Comment: thanks for another solution but my main question is why my code runs slow? by create index I expect faster execution

Comment: @mojtaba357 . . . Your query runs slowly because that is the wrong way to express what you want to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you explain? which is the right way to do it?

Comment: @ MtwStark: Gordons query reads the data once, sorts it, numbers it, done. Yours reads record per record and for every record it looks for all records with a lower date. Even if an index is used, that index tree must be scanned again and again and again. That takes long. Obviously.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sorry.. I didn't look at Gordon's query with attention, now all is very clear and very smart, thank you